# str_extract_all returns non-matching group

Tags: regex, r, perl, stringr

I'm trying to extract values from some text in R using `str_extract_all` from the `stringr` package, and I want to use a non-matching group from perl's regexps `(?:...)` to extract and clean the relevant values in one line.

When running this code:

```
library(stringr)

## Example string.
## Not the real string, but I get the same results with this one.
x <- 'WIDTH 4\nsome text that should not be matched.\n\nWIDTH   46 some text.'

## extract values
str_extract_all(x, perl('(?:WIDTH\\s+)[0-9]+'))
```

I want to get this result:

```
[[1]]
[1] "4"    "46"
```

But I get this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "WIDTH 4"    "WIDTH   46"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex still matches `WIDTH` – it just doesn't put it into a capture group. Your regex is equivalent to

```
WIDTH\s+[0-9]+
```

Your code extracts the *whole* substring that was matched by the regex. (Non-)Capture groups do not change this.

You can use a lookbehind to assert that a certain string comes before the current position, without including it in the matched substring:

```
(?<=WIDTH\s)[0-9]+
```

Depending on the exact regex engine, you cannot use variable-length patterns in a lookbehind. There is another form that can allow this:

```
WIDTH\s+\K[0-9]+
```

Comment: I know that escaping the `\s` as `\\s` will be necessary in R, but I'm not sure how to adapt the rest of it. Currently, it's returning just the first value, 4.

Comment: This answer is correct, you just have to escape the backslashes \ in the final expression so it becomes `WIDTH\\s+\\K[0-9]+`, you can test it online [here](http://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/Rweb/) and you will see it gives the right output.

Answer (score 2):

The perl zero width regular expression is wrong.

Here are solutions that do not need perl regular expressions:

```
sub("WIDTH\\s+", "", str_extract_all(x, 'WIDTH\\s+[0-9]+')[[1]])
```

or simpler:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(x, "WIDTH\\s+(\\d+)")
```

Also if we want the results returned as numeric this works:

```
strapply(x, "WIDTH\\s+(\\d+)", as.numeric)
```